# How to get the directly linked movie through wikiPageWikiLink in DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Before 12 days the below sparql query was working properly but when Dbpedia update the interface of the website in 2021 the same query could not retrieve any result. Actually there is no wikipagewikilink that was exist to connect movies and other resources.
the query that I used is

```
PREFIX dbont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
    SELECT distinct ?p ?o
    WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Terminator> ?p ?o. ?o <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> dbont:Film.}
```

The result that I got before was all movies that are linked with terminator Film by WikiPageWikiLink predicate.
but now there are no such results.

Are there any changes occurred on DBpedia server?
Is this property(WikiPageWikiLink) removed ?

Is there any other way to get the movies that are directly linked to specific movie?

Thank you.

Comment: the data is just not loaded - you can see the corresponding news and what has been loaded here: https://community.openlinksw.com/t/announcing-a-new-dbpedia-release/2194

Comment: thank you for this clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Dbpedia on Slack chat they said that there was a dataset missing in the last update. They solved the issue now and the same query that I Posted it works now. Many thanks to Patric for his follow up with databus team to solve this issue.